# How to create Circular view on android wear?

Tags: android, listview, android-wear-2.0

How can I create circular list for round watch as in android wear 2.0 ?.

Like this:

[image]

Circular list is seen in android wear app launcher.

Comment: Please check this blog article - http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/04/build-beautifully-for-android-wear.html

Comment: This will not help had checked. BoxInsetLayout sets a square inset but here items are aligned to edge (even scrollbar is circular)

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to replace your ListView with a **WearableRecyclerView**.
It can be used like a normal ListView. But make sure, you **import the right one** from `android.support.wear.widget`. **DON'T use** the one from `android.support.wearable.view`. This one should be crossed out, so it won't take you long to check if you're using the right one. If there's just one WearableRecyclerViewto choose from, make sure to add `compile 'com.android.support:wear:27.0.0'` to the dependencies in your **build.gradle** (wear) file.
Also make sure that you're using `<android.support.wear.widget.WearableRecyclerView/>` in your **activity.xml**. If you just want a circular ListView without any custom item-scaling, just call this in your `onLayoutInflated()` method:

```
your_recyclerview.setEdgeItemsCenteringEnabled(true);
your_recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new WearableLinearLayoutManager(your_activity_context));
```

If you want to make items scaling up when they get closer to the center of your screen, things get a little more complicated.

First: paste this in your Activity.java:

```
private class CustomScrollingLayoutCallback extends WearableLinearLayoutManager.LayoutCallback {

        private static final float MAX_ICON_PROGRESS = 2F;

        @Override
        public void onLayoutFinished(View child, RecyclerView parent) {

            float centerOffset = ((float) child.getHeight() / 2.0f) / (float) parent.getHeight();
            float yRelativeToCenterOffset = (child.getY() / parent.getHeight()) + centerOffset;

            float progresstoCenter = (float) Math.sin(yRelativeToCenterOffset * Math.PI);

            float mProgressToCenter = Math.abs(0.5f - yRelativeToCenterOffset);

            mProgressToCenter = Math.min(mProgressToCenter, MAX_ICON_PROGRESS);

            child.setScaleX(1 - mProgressToCenter);
            child.setScaleY(1 - mProgressToCenter);
            child.setX(+(1 - progresstoCenter) * 100);
        }

    }
```

Then go back to your **onLayoutInflated()** method, and type the following:

```
    CustomScrollingLayoutCallback customScrollingLayoutCallback = new CustomScrollingLayoutCallback();
    your_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new WearableLinearLayoutManager(your_context, customScrollingLayoutCallback));
    your_recycler_view.setCircularScrollingGestureEnabled(true);
```

done.

Comment: In my case,middle Icon Size is not Increasing the size If i Scroll up and down.How can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible with Android Wear 2.0's `WearableRecyclerView`.

According to [Android Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/wearable-recycler-view.html?utm_campaign=android_discussion_wearpreview_092916&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog#):

> Wear 2.0 introduces the `WearableRecyclerView` class for displaying and
>   manipulating a vertical list of items optimized for round displays.
>   `WearableRecyclerView` extends the existing [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) class to
>   provide a curved layout and a circular scrolling gesture in wearable
>   apps.

You may like to read more about [Android Wear 2.0 Preview 3](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/09/android-wear-2-0-developer-preview-3-play-store-and-more.html).

Comment: People who're downvoting this answer, please post your reasoning at least. This isn't a "link-only" answer. It quotes relevant text from the link. And if you've got a better answer then please don't hide behind a down vote, instead post it as an answer.

Comment: The circular scrollbar is showing up as straight :(